# Next.js mongoose returns only 20 records although no filter is set

Tags: mongoose, next.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I have the problem that when I work with Next.js and the revalidate method /getServerSideProps, my result only ever contains 20 data although there are 112. If I change the whole thing to 'no-store', all 112 data are returned. I use the App Router method.

The strange thing is that in the GET method where the call to mongoose takes place, I can see all the records. However, only 20 in the action.js

app/Products/route.js:

```
export async function GET(request) {
try {
 await mongoConection();
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
}

const products = await Product.find({}).sort({
 createdAt: -1,
});

//Products length = 112
console.log("Products length" + products.length);

return NextResponse.json({ products });

}
```

app/FetchProducts/action.js:

```
"use server";

export async function FetchProducts() {
const result = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/Products`, {
 next: { revalidate: 3 },
});

const expected = await result.json();

//expectedlength = 20
console.log("expected length: " + expected.products.length);

return expected;

}
```

app/FetchProducts/page.js:

```
 const fetchProducts = async () => {
 setLoadMore(true);

 const fetching = await FetchProducts();

 //ONLY 20 Result
 setResult(fetching.products);

 setLoadMore(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#data-fetching-without-fetch)

> Any data fetching libraries that do not use fetch directly will not
> affect caching of a route, and will be static or dynamic depending on
> the route segment

in `GET` route you are not using `fetch`. that is why you are getting all the results. but in actions you use `fetch` and probably your first `fetch` request returned only 20 and those were cached.